# How to customize page numbering style

Tags: page-numbering, books

It is a nice style to put page numbers in a filled black (or grey) box which touch the edge of the paper. How to create such a book?

Further, how to create hanging out boxes and how to put *crop signs* in the corners (it is necessary for printing).

Comment: As always you should start with an MWE. Give us more information: Documentclass, stuff like fancyhdr, footmarks,... Are you willing and able to use PS-tricks or TikZ. At least give a complete document which will result in one pagenumber in order to save that typing to us.

Answer (score 5):

Here is  a simple solution with `titlesec/titleps` for the page numbers at the edge of the paper sheet:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\sethead[\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\evensidemargin +\hoffset + 1in\relax][l]{\colorbox{SlateGray4}{\textcolor{white}{\huge\bfseries\thepage}}}}][][]{}{}{\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\evensidemargin +\hoffset + 1in\relax][r]{\colorbox{SlateGray4}{\textcolor{white}{\huge\bfseries\thepage}}}}}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

To have page numbers exactly at the corner of the sheets, you can use this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\sethead[{\raisebox{\dimexpr\topmargin + \voffset + 1in\relax}[\height][0pt]{\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\evensidemargin +\hoffset + 1in\relax][l]{\colorbox{SlateGray4}{\textcolor{white}{\huge\bfseries\thepage}}}}}}][][]
{}{}{\raisebox{\dimexpr\topmargin + \voffset + 1in\relax}[\height][0pt]{\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\evensidemargin +\hoffset + 1in\relax][r]{\colorbox{SlateGray4}{\textcolor{white}{\huge\bfseries\thepage}}}}}}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\setcounter{page}{121}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-16]

\end{document}
```

[image: adding stub image description to hack around the annoying minimum 6 characters per edit rule]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I need some modifications, because I want numbers touching the top edge.

Comment: I'll modify in a moment. I didn't understand well your specification.

Comment: @user3058699: here you are, Mylord!